# does read() clear kernel ring buffer /proc/kmsg?

Tags: linux, logging, linux-kernel, buffer

I developed my own log processing program. To process logs originated from `printk()`, I read from kernel ring buffer like this:

```c
#define _PATH_KLOG "/proc/kmsg"
CGR_INT kernelRingBufferFileDescriptor = open(_PATH_KLOG, O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK);
CGR_CHAR kernelLogMessage[MAX_KERNEL_RING_BUFFER + 1] = {'\0'};
while (1)
{
    ...
    read(kernelRingBufferFileDescriptor, kernelLogMessage + residueSize, MAX_KERNEL_RING_BUFFER);
    ...
}
```

my program is in user space. I remember whenever someone use `read()` to read data in the ring buffer (like I did above), the part that is read will be cleared from the ring buffer. Is it the case, or is it not?

I am confused about this, since there is always something in the ring buffer, and as a result, my program is very busy processing all these logs. So I am not sure is it because some module is keeping sending logs to me or is it because I read the same logs again and again since logs are not cleared.

TO figure out, I use `klogctl()` to check the ring buffer:

```c
CGR_CHAR buf[MAX_KERNEL_RING_BUFFER] = {0};
int byteCount = klogctl(4, buf, MAX_KERNEL_RING_BUFFER - 1);    /* 4 -- Read and clear all messages remaining in the ring buffer */
printf("%s %d: data read from kernel ring buffer = \"%s\"\n",__FILE__, __LINE__, buf);
```

and I keep getting data all the time. Since `klogctl()` with argument 4 read and clear ring buffer, I kind of believing some module DOES sending logs to me all the time.

Can anyone tell me - does `read()` clear ring buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Become root and run this `cat /proc/kmsg >> File1.txt` and `cat /proc/kmsg >> File2.txt`. Compare `File1.txt` and `File2.txt` You will immediately know whether the ring buffer is getting cleared on `read()` cos `cat` internally invokes `read()` anyways!

Also read about ring buffers and how they behave in the Kernel Documentation here-
http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/trace/ring-buffer-design.txt

**EDIT**: I found something interesting in the [book](http://tjworld.net/books/ldd3/) `Linux Device Drivers` by Jonathan Corbet-

> The printk function writes messages into a circular buffer that is
>   **__LOG_BUF_LEN** bytes long: a value from **4 KB** to **1 MB** chosen while configuring the kernel. The function then wakes any process that is
>   waiting for messages, that is, any process that is sleeping in the
>   **syslog** system call or that is reading **/proc/kmsg**. These two interfaces
>   to the logging engine are almost equivalent, but note that **reading
>   from /proc/kmsg consumes the data from the log buffer**, whereas the
>   **syslog** system call can optionally return log data while leaving it for
>   other processes as well. In general, reading the **/proc** file is easier
>   and is the default behavior for **klogd**. The **dmesg** command can be used
>   to look at the content of the buffer without flushing it; actually,
>   the command returns to **stdout** the whole content of the buffer, whether
>   or not it has already been read

So in your particular case, if you are using a plain `read()`, I think the buffer is indeed getting cleared and new data is being constantly written into it and hence you find some data all the time! Kernel experts can correct me here!

Comment: very helpful. thanks.
"The function then wakes any process that is waiting for messages...", but in my code of reading the ring buffer, it seems my program is not waken by the printk() function. right?
Another question, is "/proc/kmsg" a FIFO? I know it is not a regular file.

Comment: @martial Yes `/proc/kmsg` is a circular FIFO like buffer!

Comment: @martial How do you say that `printk()` is not waking your function? If your program is not able to read from `proc/kmsg` and that makes you feel that your program is not waking up, then I think it is because your process is repeatedly losing to an already running `syslogd` which also contends for reading /proc/kmsg

Answer (score 0):

From reading the `do_syslog` function, it seems that messages are cleared when they're read.
By your description, you get the same behavior with `klogctl(4)`, which also clears the buffer, so it makes sense.

So maybe there's indeed someone that keeps writing messages.
You can find which `printk` it is, by the text, disable it, and see what you get. Or you can add the `jiffies` value to the message, so you'll know if you keep getting new messages, or are these are the same ones.